# Correct Radar Range Equation for SNR at Detection

Tags: signal-detection, snr, radar

Assuming you'd like to estimate the probability of detection of a target for a monostatic radar.

For estimating detection SNR of a monostatic radar for given target rcs signature, do you use the energy or power form of the SNR equation?

[Budge's Radar Equation Notes](http://www.ece.uah.edu/courses/material/EE619-2011/RadarRangeEquation(2)2011.pdf)

Energy form of the SNR equation:
[image: Energy form of the SNR equation]

Power form of the SNR equation:
[image]

Comment: Im not a fan of the Radar equation

Comment: I hate the time out on edits.  tao of p is equal 1/B in his notes so they should be the same.  Ive never seen anyone use units in a unit less ratio before.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz Why aren't you a fan of the "radar" equation?. Some people I know with the same opinion usually say because it's an "overextended Friis transmission equation"; or they have a more pedantic reason like "Because it's not called the Friis transmission equation".

Comment: @Envidia .  It isn't really universal.  There was a paper written in JASA about 20 years ago that noted that when you have a an active ping on an air filled steel cylinder , that is 30 feet in diameter and 300 feet long, suspended in 100 feet of water, the target strength and path loss terms are not independent.   The careful decomposition of terms as separate engineering quantities breaks down.  There are lots of cases where where the SONAR/RADAR/LINK_BUDGET equations need fudge factors to be accurate.  Engineers tend to think of these as fundamental when they are really idealizations.

Comment: Back in the day, and even today they can be useful but a lot can be economically computed directly using things like Finite Element Models.  The other criticism, is that terms like NRD (recognition differential) can be unreliable with humans in the loop.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz Was the experiment also conducted with electromagnetic waves? Or just sound?

Comment: JASA = Journal of the Acoustical Society of America . "air filled steel cylinder , that is 30 feet in diameter and 300 feet long, suspended in 100 feet of water" $\approx$  sub.  so no, not electromagnetic.

Comment: If you want to stick to electromagnetic.  There is a certain RADAR on Cape Cod, in the Commonwealth of Massachusetts, looking eastward.  Cape Cod has some reasonable average wind, so there is a lot of interest in establishing wind farms.  Where do you plug a wind farm into the RADAR equation?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz That was a slightly loaded question: I know that the experiment was conducted using sound. I bet that the same experiment conducted with electromagnetic waves, along other caveats, would better reflect the radar equation as we know it. The equation is based on electromagnetic theory, after all. Seeing disparities by applying the radar equation to a non-RF radar system shouldn't be a surprise and is why you can't plug in a wind farm into the radar equation.

Comment: It’s based on the wave equation There is nothing beyond the scaler wave equation in what is shown above. An electromagnetic equation would be vector valued.